# Forms Authentication & Virtual Directory

Tags: iis, authentication, forms

We're having trouble getting Forms Authentication to work with a virtual directory in IIS.

We have a main site, and then a microsite setup within a virtual directory. This mircosite has its own admin system within an "Admin" folder, which has authentication on it but currently it is not kicking in and the admin section is browsable by anyone.

The web.config with the admin folder has the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <appSettings/>
    <connectionStrings/>
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="?"/>
        </authorization>
        <customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="~/Admin/Error.aspx"/>
    </system.web>
</configuration>
```

Could anyone give me any clues as to why this might not be working?

Cheers!

Comment: Turns out it was being caused because of a <clear /> tag in the web.config in the microsite. As the main site is an MCMS site this was causing problems!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if you set this in the `web.config` at the root of your site instead:

```
<location path="MicroSite/Admin">
  <system.web>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?"/>
    </authorization>
  </system.web>
</location>
```